# jGravity (jQuery plugin) not dragging in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, gravity

I'm using this jquery plugin http://tinybigideas.com/plugins/jquery-gravity/

I'm on a mac and the drag feature works like a dream in chrome and safari but in Firefox my objects won't drag. In IE 10 the objects don't even have gravity applied to them... but thats IE.

even the demo does not work in firefox http://www.tinybigideas.com/assets/demo/jquery-gravity/

here is what i'm using
    `$('#ballpit').jGravity({
        target: 'div',
        ignoreClass: '',
        weight: 25,
        depth: 5,
        drag: true
    });`

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Surely you can dream up a title which actually summarizes the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm *pretty* late to this but recently used jGravity and thought I'd leave this here for anyone else who stumbles across this.

I'd recommend that when testing jGravity, select a containing element such as the body or a container, as opposed to #ballpit (not sure what it is in this context), but generally you'll want the objects to bounce around within a container or the body.

That way the 'target' value will respond to the space within the element you called jGravity() on.

your code would look like:

```
$('.container').jGravity({
    target: '.someClass',
    ignoreClass: '',
    weight: 25,
    depth: 5,
    drag: true
});
```

not sure why the drag option isnt working for you in Firefox unfortunately, but the demo link doesn't seem to lead to the demo anymore.